# Call same javascript function timepicker twice

Tags: javascript

I have problem with calling same javascript function twice. When I run code, first input field with id="time" works, but second with id="time1" wont.

```js
var timepicker = new TimePicker('time', {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});
timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {

  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;
});


var timepicker1 = new TimePicker('time1', {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});
timepicker1.on('change', function(evt1) {

  var value1 = (evt1.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt1.minute || '00');
  evt1.element.value = value1;
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Time">
</div>
<input type="text" id="time1" placeholder="Time">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you see console errors?

Comment: "won't work" doesn't give us much of a clue about your problem. Do you get some error or other unexpected behaviour? Have you stepped through your code with the debugger to see what's happening? Which timepicker plugin is this? What are `evt` and `evt1` - they're undefined in your code above?

Comment: @ADyson `evt` and `evt1` are parameters in the function

Comment: @Mark sorry yes they are, my mistake

Comment: Ok I made a runnable snippet. Apart from having a missing opening `<div>` tag, your code looks fine. It seems to show the picker on both fields. Clicking on a time in the first one throws an error. Clicking on a time in the second one simply doesn't do anything. Is that the problem you were trying to describe? Do you get an error for the first one in your real environment?

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify an array of targets.
So your code looks like this:

```js
var timepicker = new TimePicker(['time','time1'], {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});
timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js">
  </script>
<input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Time">
<input type="text" id="time1" placeholder="Time">
```

Comment: Is there a way to have one timepicker for lang: 'en' and another for a different lang?